# Convert Date to String in JAVA

Tags: java, date

I have `java.util.Date` `02/26/2015`. I want to convert it like `Feburary 26,2015` as `String`. How can I convert it like that ??

like what goes here ??

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("here");
```

Comment: Use DateFormatter and format.

Comment: Yeah but what should be the formate ?? like what goes here ?? `DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("here");`

Comment: Have you read the docs?

Comment: SO should automatically close such questions.

Comment: The duplicate you've suggested is *not* a duplicate - it's going the other way. But there *are* lots of duplicates... and as isnot2bad says, the documentation is reasonably clear. Did you read the docs for `SimpleDateFormat` before asking? SO is not an alternative to research - it should be where you turn *after* researching the problem thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this format:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd,yyyy");
```

As descripted in the [documentation of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> E    Day name in week
>   d    Day in month
>   y    Year

Answer (score 1):

You use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,  yyyy");
```

The format above is:

```
MMMM Month in year,
dd Day in month,
yyyy Year,
```

Please read the manual for more possibilities of how to format dates properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,  yyyy");
```

Comment: Doesn't really describe how you got to the answer, just tells the OP the answer. Not really helpful for teaching.

Comment: M -month in words  d-day in numbers y-year in numbers      MMM-Jan MMMM-january  yyyy- 4 digit year

Comment: A link to the manual would have been better. is what I was getting at.